# Numpy: Using an index array to set values in a 3D array

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray

I have an `indices` array of shape (2, 2, 3) which looks like this:

```
array([[[ 0,  6, 12],
        [ 0,  6, 12]],
       [[ 1,  7, 13],
        [ 1,  7, 13]]])
```

I want to use these as **indices** to set some values of a `np.zeros` matrix to 1. While the highest value in this example is a 13, I know that it can go up to 18. This is why I created `one_hot = np.zeros((2, 2, 18))` array:

```
array([[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],
       [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]])
```

Using the `indices` array, my desired outcome is this:

```
array([[[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],
       [[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]]])
```

I want to use numpy's advanced indexing sort of like this:

`one_hot[indices] = 1`

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible solution:

```
np.put_along_axis(one_hot, indices, 1, axis=2)
```

Output:

```
[[[1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]

 [[0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]]
```